# how to select a div by class name intersection

Tags: jquery, css

```
<div class="c1 c2">
<div class="c1">
<div class="c2">
```

how to select the first div: `<div class="c1 c2">`
Is there any way to do with it?
thx

Comment: select using `div.c1.c2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code, it will do the intersection selection :

```
$('.c1.c2')
```

Below code will give you union selection:

```
$(".c1, .c2")
```

Answer (score 2):

`$('.c1.c2')` will solve your purpose. When you enter multiple selectors in this fashion, it will match all those elements which have both these classes present on the same element.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not completely clear. Are you trying to select the first div using CSS or using jQuery?

If CSS, then you can select it using `div.c1.c2`.
This will only match the div that have both the classes.

If you are trying to select it with jQuery, try `$(".c1.c2")`.
Again, this will match only the elements with both classes, just like CSS.

Comment: by the way , you've missed a ".", $("c1.c2") -> $(".c1.c2")

Comment: Oh, my bad! I've added the dot. :)